# Json Array Not Working

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file like below. And I'm using jquery 1.10.1

```
    var jsonData =
  [
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "image": "Content/Uploads/f1d59b7e-c93a-4419-94a6-6514d1c2384.jpg",
        "textstyles": {
          "pricecolour": "FFF",
          "checkincolour": "222"
        },
        "products": [
          {
            "product": "Product-1",
            "price": "55776"
          },
          {
            "product": "Product-2",
            "price": "24776"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I used this code for sorting by price under the data => products

```
    function SortJsonData(prop, asc, jsonData) {
            jsonData = jsonData.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
                else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
            });
            return jsonData;
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
        SortJsonData('price', true, jsonData);
});
```

But not sorting, write randomly.

I need a sorting by price of product json string. How can i write this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think below line of code would solve your purpose.

```
function sortJsonData(prop, asc, json) {
            json = json.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (asc) 
                    return a[prop] - b[prop];
                else
                    return b[prop] - a[prop];
            });
            return json;
    }
```

And make call to function like below,because you only want to sort the products part of JSON to be sorted so only pass that part to the function call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sortJsonData('price',true,jsonData.data[0].products);
});
```

Now print the original jsonData.You will see a sorted list.

```
console.log(jsonData.data[0].products);
```

Comment: first of all, thank you. Yeah you're right, I see ONLY sorted list. But I need all jsonData with sorted products. How can i?

Comment: what is your JSON fix structure?  as per my understanding jsonData may contains multiple data and each data will contains three object(image,textstyles,products) only. and you want to sort the product list only fot that each data inside jsonData?  Please correct me if i am wrong.